# Unable to match first letter of every word in string

Tags: regex, xregexp

I would like a regex to match the first letter of every word in a string.

I am using the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) Javascript library.

I am actually trying to copy a regex I have in my server-side C# code (seemingly working fine):

```
new Regex(@"\b[\p{L}]|(?<=[-])[\p{L}]").[omitted code]
```

Starting small, I have tried the following:

```
XRegExp.exec("foo bar", XRegExp("\\b\\p{L}", "g"))
```

I expected `["f","b"]` (using the 'all matches' flag (g), but only got: `["f"]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use String.split() instead to break up the tokens, then just iterate those strings and take value.getChar(0). Wouldn't that be easier and more maintainable?

Comment: That does sound easier. I only nedd to split on white-spaces and hyphens anyway, so string.Split() should work just fine. Thanks! I still wonder why XRegExp didn't work as planned, though ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting both `f` and `b` because [`exec()`](http://xregexp.com/api/#exec) finds matches successively on each call.

It is usually used in a `while` loop to find all the matches.

If you were using the native library, then I would have advised you to use [`string.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch) to find all the matches at once.

Check the documentation of [`exec()`](http://xregexp.com/api/#exec) in your situation, and then look for a method similar to [`string.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch).

Comment: Thanks! :) I had missed the "successively on each call"-part. The reason I am using XRegExp is I needed support for Unicode when using shorthand character classes (\d, \w, \b etc.). I believe the native library [only supports ASCII](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-and-unicode).